# Getting Close event of another (programmatically opened) browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I am opening a new browser window on a click event. Is there a way that bound the close event of the child window from the parent

**Sample html**:

```
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<label id="lbl"></label>
```

**Script**:

```
$(function () {
    $("#btn").on('click', function () {
        window.open("about:blank", "test", "height=200px,width=200px");
        $("#lbl").html("Opend");
    });
});
```

Lest say for example, I want to change the label text to `closed` when the child is closed.

[Js Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/p48eu9ng/)

Comment: use `window.close` the same way you have used `window.open`. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp) refer here

Comment: @user2688337  thanks for your suggestion. But i am not trying to close the window i am trying to be notified when its closing by user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onbeforeunload` event:

```
var new_window = window.open("about:blank", "test", "height=200px,width=200px");
new_window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    alert('closed');
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/p48eu9ng/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function(){

    $("#btn").on('click',function(){

       var new_window = window.open("about:blank","test","height=200px,width=200px");
        new_window.onbeforeunload = function(){ $("#lbl").html("Closed");}
        $("#lbl").html("Opend");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/p48eu9ng/4/), changing label to close after closing new window.

```
$(function(){

    $("#btn").on('click',function(){        
    var newWindow = window.open("about:blank","test","height=200px,width=200px");
        $("#lbl").html("Opend");        
    $(newWindow).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
        $("#lbl").html("Closed");
    })    
    });
```